# if $\mu(E)=0$ then $\int_E f d\mu=0$, even if $f(x)= \infty$ for all x in E

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

The stament to prove is: If $\mu(E)=0$ then $\int_E f\ d\mu = 0$ even if $f(x)=\infty$ for every $x \in E$.
Thou, i already check on this web if this was answer and, as i thought, it has. But uses the fact that $\int_E f\ d\mu = \int_X \chi_E f\ d\mu$. It should be not a problem, thou, in the book this fact is proposed after. So, i suposse that it could be proven without it. $$$$
If $f(x) \not= 0$ for all $x \in E$, given that $\mu(B) \geq 0$ for all measurable set B, then the only way that sup$\int_E s\ d\mu=$sup$\sum_{i=0}^m \alpha_i \mu(A_i\cap E)=0$ it is if $\mu(A_i \cap E) = 0$. Where the supreme its taken on all simple and measurable functions such that $0\leq s = \sum_{i=0}^m\alpha_i\chi_{A_i}\leq f$ $$$$
Taking this approach, idk how to show that $\mu(A_i\cap E)= 0$ for some $A_i=\{x \in X : s(x)=\alpha_i\}$. Of course, it may happen that my assumption its not true. In either case, im stuck. Any tips or directions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A_i \cap E \subseteq E$, $\mu(A_i \cap E) \leqslant \mu(E)=0$ by monotonicity.

Comment: God, it was so simple. Thanks